# Can a machine learning algorithm learn to differentiate a function?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

As the question says, can a machine learning algorithm learn to differentiate a function?(Eg. If we give such a network a function $f(x)$, it should output its derivative $f'(x)$.)

Clearly, a simple feed forward neural network should not be able to do so, but I have a strong feeling that recurrent neural networks can.

Has this been done before? How complex does the network have to be?

Comment: You absolutely can train a ML model but we can write a program to do this deterministically quite effectively. Look up symbolic differentiation for algebraic/mathematical contexts and automatic differentiation for computer programs. Both are described in resources such as Wikipedia. Both rely heavily on the chain rule to break down the problem into smaller and smaller pieces until known rules apply (such as differentiating a polynomial). Stringing together smaller transformations yields the complete derivative. Similarly, automatic differentiation proceeds using operator overloading.

Comment: Integration is a different beast as there is no chain rule and so there is no way to divide-and-conquer. There have been efforts such as https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-98392-z. I would not say these efforts are mainstream or what is used in the academic community.

Comment: At the moment, AFAIK, Mathematica's native engine is the state-of-the-art for applied practitioners (i.e., someone studying or working in a substantive domain) for symbolic integration, and a wealth of quasi Monte Carlo and Monte Carlo methods exist for computational/approximation approaches. Here too progress has been made using neural networks, for instance through the use of Normalizing Flows. Broadly though, there is no one solution that works for all situations. In some cases, you may want Markov Chain Monte Carlo to compute the integral, in others Gauss-Hermite quadrature, etc.

Comment: @AnirbanMukherjee Thanks for the comments. I realise using a NN is not the best way to differentiate a function. However, I'm asking with the context of applying NNs to modelling problems in mind. If the gradient of the input is needed to solve the modelling problem at hand, then it is foreseeable that the network can learn this. I was wondering if anyone has ever tried to use a NN in this manner. I'm not too familiar with the capabilities of NNs however, and couldn't find any paper on differentiation using NNs.

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean by the "gradient of the input". If you mean the gradient of any function applied to input features then you can always get that gradient from TF or PyTorch if the function is written using backend functions instead of plain vanilla Python, even if the function is applied prior to putting the input into a neural network. Basically any function written using TF or PyTorch will always automatically give you gradients if you want them. HTH.

Comment: @AnirbanMukherjee  What I mean is this: We input into the model which differentiates a series of datapoints: {x, f(x)}, and it outputs a series {f'(x)}, the gradient at each of the points inputted. It is not possible to make a feedforward neural network that does this for any function f(x), as it only considers each point individually, and cannot compare it with the previous or next to find the gradient.

Comment: If you're interested in the theoretical answer, I think the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) guarantees that such a NN exists. The caveat is that you do not know the width of such a network (could be 
extremely large) , nor you are guaranteed to find that with optimization.

Comment: Yep. As long as $f'$ is continuous in $x$ and you are considering a compact domain, a neural network will always exist that can approximate $f'$. In some theorems, the width is unbounded. In others, the depth is unbounded. There are many theorems on the subject. I still don't get why you would want to compute $f'$ using the NN but if you are thinking of computational amortisation akin to what is done in BayesFlow, it is possible. Its also not impossibly difficult to train the network (I have worked on something similar in the past).

Comment: @AnirbanMukherjee Consider the case where you want to fit a NN model to velocity and acceleration data, meaning that you input a time series of velocity info and it outputs the acceleration (not the best use-case, but bear with me). This implies that the NN learns to differentiate. It is useful when modelling complex systems that may (to some extent) depend on the derivative of some variable. When training a NN, you would ideally want the NN to identify and reproduce this dependence.

Comment: The universal approximation theorem says you can approximate the second derivative (as long as it exists and is reasonable). I doubt though that you would beat a simple rubric such as velocity(t+1) = velocity(t) + acc(t)int, where int is the time interval. I will stop here. The answer to your question is that, yes, both conceptually and empirically, one can build a network to derive acc from vel. You may choose to either a FF or a recurrent network. There are universal approximation theorems that guarantee the conceptual basis of this approach in recurrent networks.

Comment: I am not aware a universal approximation theorem for transformers. I would imagine you could build one that way and I would also imagine there are universal approximation theorems that apply but it's not my area of focus. HTH.